# C++ Output a Byte Clarification

Tags: byte, output, bit-shift, putchar

From textbook:

[image]

So I know a byte has 8 bits and the right bit-shift adds zero bits to the left and pops off bits from the right. 
But how is it used the above example to output a byte?
I would've expected:

```
putchar(b >> 8)
putchar(b >> 7)
putchar(b >> 6)
etc.
```

Since I assume putchar outputs the popped off bits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

putchar prints the ascii character corresponding to the integer given.

`putchar(0x41)` converts the integer 0x41 into an `unsigned char` (with a size of one byte) and prints out the ascii character corresponding to 0x41 (which is "A").

The key thing to realize here that putchar only looks at the lower 8 bits, i.e. `putchar(0x41)` and `putchar(0xffffff41)` do the same thing.

Now let's look at what happens when you pass something to your function above.

`outbyte(0x41424344);`

first it bitshifts b by 24 bits, and then calls putchar on that value
`0x41424344 << 24; //0x00000041`
`putchar(0x00000041); //A`

then it bitshifts b by 16 bits, and then calls putchar on that value
`0x41424344 << 24; //0x00004142`
`putchar(0x00004142); //B`

etc.

Here it is in action: http://ideone.com/3xeFSx

Comment: Ooooh, so the textbook made a mistake on the last putchar call.